# Difference between multiple regression with categorical independent variables versus numerous univariate regressions?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, logit, univariate

I have a dataset about the functionality of rural water supply points (boreholes etc) and I am undertaking a logit regression. My independent variables of interest are the type of water point (about 5 categories) and the year of construction (1950-2016, so I consider this as a continuous variable). The dependent variable is a boolean (water point is currently functional? yes/no). I could set up dummy boolean variables for my categories and proceed with a logit multiple regression from there.

I understand that multiple regression could be advantageous because it handles covariance of the independent variables (eg [this example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41633/sign-flipping-when-adding-one-more-variable-in-regression-and-with-much-greater/41645#41645) or [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127370/multiple-regression-or-separate-simple-regressions) ). 
However, it's hard to understand how this sort of thinking applies where one of my independent variables is unordered categorical.

From the above reading, I suspect that multiple regression could take care of an effect such as a tendency to build fewer boreholes (type1) in the last 10 years whilst preference to build wells (type5) has increased - ie, that "year of construction" and "type" correlate to each other. But when I ask my logit model to predict functionality, I have to input **both** independent variables anyway, to get my prediction out. Why doesn't this wholly take care of said effect?

In this case, where I could easily run 5 univariate logit regressions (one for each type of water point) or otherwise could run a multiple regression using all the available data, what are the conceptual advantages or disadvantages of each approach? Does each method answer a slightly different statistical 'question'? How does the extra data, from waterpoint types 2-5, actually influence the prediction of functionality for waterpoint type 1?

Thanks