# when some of your coefficients in multivariate logistic regression model is negative

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression

when some of your coefficients in multivariate logistic regression model is negative while i know  these variable have positive sign in univariate model, What should I do؟

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you describe what you mean by "univariate model"? And maybe describe the results you're getting in a little more detail.

Comment: This question is also answered at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41633 (for general regression).

Answer (score 2):

This is a general phenomena caused by correlation between your independent variables.  Here's a small example I constructed for you to experiment with.  I demonstrated with a linear regression as the phenomena is easier to see pictorially in this case, but it also happens with any generalized linear model, including logistic regressions.

First, let's create a vector of random uniform values

```
x_1 <- runif(200, 0, 1)
```

and then construct another vector that is explicitly correlated with `x_1`

```
x_2 <- .5*x_1 + rnorm(200, 0, .25)
```

Since I forced a statstical dependency between `x_1` and `x_2`, these random variables are correlated

```
cor(matrix(c(x_1, x_2), ncol=2))
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.5059403
[2,] 0.5059403 1.0000000
```

You can see this geometrically with a scatterplot

[image]

Now let's make a dependent variable that depends on both

```
y <- 3*x_1 - x_2 + rnorm(200, 0, .1)
```

This collection of three variables show the behavior that you are witnessing.  Putting `x_2` in a *univariate* model shows a positive coefficient

```
df <- data.frame(x_1=x_1, x_2=x_2, y=y)

# Univariate model
lm(y~x_2, data=df)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x_2, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          x_2  
     1.1152       0.5061
```

In fact, you can see that *both* `x_1` and `x_2` are positively correlated with `y` in a picture

[image][image]

But if I put them all together, I get recover the true negative coefficient for `x_2`!

```
# Multivariate model
lm(y ~ x_1 + x_2, data=df)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x_1 + x_2, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          x_1          x_2  
   -0.01096      3.00800     -1.00790
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide this detailed example!

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason is that the remaining variables of the fitted model influence the changing of the sign!