# How can i correct a variable that is significant for the same model in one year and not in the other year?

Tags: regression, econometrics, stata, eviews

I need some help with my master's dissertation.

I am using a simple regression, often used in literature that establishes a relationship between `Price=B1+B2 Equity+ Net Result`.

However, in reviewing the results I have the following problem:

-> If we analyse separately the equity variable(X) in relation to price(Y) it is significant at the 5% level, however in the model with the net result it is no longer significant.

-> In the following year separately or together the equity variable is significant.

I am afraid that in the defense of the dissertation the question will be raised because in a model (year 2017) equity is not significant and in the following year it is.

p.s the correlation between variables and own capital is very high but close for the two years 
0.8

Comment: Could you build a common model for the two years?

Comment: thank you for your comment! the metedology used in the study is composed of two analyses in which both use the same base model is only disaggregated , so they are already a common model, is there any other way that sugest?

Comment: Can you show the details (that is, formulas) of the model you have used?

Comment: I think I have found out what the problem is, maybe it is because in one model I was including the half-yearly net income and in the other model the annual net income and these differences may be affecting the explanatory power of own capital. How can I explain that the inclusion of different variables in the model may be affecting the significance of the others?

Comment: Then maybe you can answer your own question? As for the last Q in comment, see for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/338789/predictor-flipping-sign-in-regression-with-no-multicollinearity (and a LOT of other posts here, do a serch)