# Coefficient of one independent variable in Cox regression flips when inserting two other independet variables together

Tags: cox-model, proportional-hazards

I'm running a cox regression to test the effect of different variables on crime.

There's one independent variable of interest (X), for which I hypothesize a negative relationship with crime (i.e., HR<1). This is usually what I get, also when I include several control variables.
However, when I insert two specific independent variables (let's call them A and B) to the model together, I get a significant HR>1 for X. When I insert each one without the other (and with all other control variables), the coefficient of X remain <1.
Any idea what could cause this?

I checked for multicollinearity and all VIF's are at least 0.7. I also tried to insert an interaction term between A and B, and it is significant, but the coefficient of X is still positive (HR>1).

Thanks!

Comment: There might be nothing specific to a Cox model here. This type of thing happens in all sorts of regression models. See for example [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/31841/28500), or [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/338789/28500), or [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1580/28500). As you don't (yet) show any examples of the results you are getting, it's hard to say much else. If you think that there's something specific to a survival model in your situation, then please edit the question to provide more details about what you've found so far.